# Capturing the output of a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, jsoup

Using C#, PowerShell and Jsoup I've tried to capturing the percentage that is displayed at the end, 99.96%. Using the DOM explorer in IE, this is what I see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <body id="website#22;page">
   <div id="wrap">
     <script type="text/javascript">...</script>
     <div class="topRow" id="iTopRow">...</div>
     <div id="header">...</div>
     <div id="content">
       <div class="paddingfix">
         <script type="text.javascript">...</script>
         <div class="toppaddingfix"></div>
         <div title="Summary Percentage"
         class="overallPercentage">
           <div>
             <div style="padding-bottom: 12px;">
               <div class="textRegionContainer" id="iTextRegion_D14">
                 <div class="position" style="display: none;"<>/div>
                 <div class="status" style="display: none;">loaded</div>
                 <div class="textRegionPlaceHolder">
                   <p class="textRegionTitle">
                     99.96 %
                   </p>
                 </div>
               </div>
            </div>
```

However, when programmatically trying to capture it I receive this:

```
<div id="iTextRegion_DR14" class="textRegionContainer">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var client = new wLive.Service.Client(false);
            var textRegion = new wLive.Controls.TextRegion(
                'Tools',
                'AppServerOutDetails3',
                'DR14',
                '#iTextRegion_DR14',
                {"id":"DR14","data":null,"paragraphs":["<bindingref       
                name=\"Reliability\" \/> %\u000d\u000a        "],"style":0},
               client);
            wLive.Controls.DataBridge.registerDataRegion('#iDataBridge', textRegion);
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

How do I programmatically capture that percentage so I can then have another program evaluate it's value?

Comment: Sounds like it's rewriting the `#iTextRegion_DR14` DOM node with the Javascript. You might want to use something like [casper](http://casperjs.org/) or [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), which can look at the DOM after the Javascript code runs.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try using casper and selenium.

Comment: Can you modify this code at all?  JavaScript is very flexible... at a minimum you should be able to duck punch something in to capture this output.

Comment: No, I can't modify the code. It's owned by an external team, but they help monitor part of the services my team owns. :(